# Assign value to pandas DataFrame with hierarchical index based on stacked condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, indexing

I have a pandas DataFrame with a two-level hierarchical index. I would like to set a value based on a condition from a certain subset to a different subset.

I think this is best explained with a small example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

example = pd.DataFrame({'ind_1': 5*[0] + 5*[1], 'ind_2': np.concatenate([np.arange(5), np.arange(5)]),
                        'col_1': np.random.random(size=10), 'col_2': np.random.random(size=10)})
example = example.set_index(['ind_1', 'ind_2'])
example_0 = example.loc[0]
example_1 = example.loc[1]
example['condition'] = False

condition = example_1['col_1'] > 0.5
```

with the DataFrames

```
$ example
                col_1     col_2  condition
ind_1 ind_2                               
0     0      0.430966  0.064335      False
      1      0.631710  0.313696      False
      2      0.354766  0.479626      False
      3      0.548612  0.793249      False
      4      0.144033  0.352583      False
1     0      0.586365  0.578001      False
      1      0.306403  0.399591      False
      2      0.312621  0.439042      False
      3      0.010637  0.232054      False
      4      0.762034  0.293433      False

$ example_0
          col_1     col_2
ind_2                    
0      0.430966  0.064335
1      0.631710  0.313696
2      0.354766  0.479626
3      0.548612  0.793249
4      0.144033  0.352583

$ example_1
          col_1     col_2
ind_2                    
0      0.586365  0.578001
1      0.306403  0.399591
2      0.312621  0.439042
3      0.010637  0.232054
4      0.762034  0.293433

$ condition
ind_2
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
```

Now I would like to assign a value as follows

```
example.loc[0].loc[condition] = True
```

which results (rightfully so) in a `SettingWithCopyWarning` and simply not work in a more complex case.

The expected output would be

```
$ example
                col_1     col_2  condition
ind_1 ind_2                               
0     0      0.430966  0.064335      True
      1      0.631710  0.313696      False
      2      0.354766  0.479626      False
      3      0.548612  0.793249      False
      4      0.144033  0.352583      True
1     0      0.586365  0.578001      False
      1      0.306403  0.399591      False
      2      0.312621  0.439042      False
      3      0.010637  0.232054      False
      4      0.762034  0.293433      False
```

So for `ind_1 == 0` we set condition. But note that condition was calculated for `ind_1 == 1`

What would be cleanest way of doing this?

Comment: Could you show your expected output? You can assign your `condition` array to a column directly (`df["condition"] = df["col_1"] > 0.5`)

Comment: Just edited the question to clarify. Your suggestion won't work because I don't want to change the df for `ind_1 == 1`

Comment: Ahhh, I see. If you want to use your index as data, I recommend not including those columns in the index. In this case, `df["condition"] = (df.index.get_level_values('ind_1') == 0) & (df["col_1"] > 0.5)` should do it (and it should be clear how much easier this would be if `ind_1` was a normal column

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I still don't think it would work.

Maybe to clarify, I want to set condition for `ind_1 == 0` but the condition itself is calculated for `ind_1 == 1`. 
So I am not looking at `col_1` itself but rather on `col_1` for `ind_1 == 1`.

Comment: Yeah, what's what the `&` operator handles

Comment: Still doesn't adress the issue. If you run this and compare it with the expected output you'll see the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `reindex` on `condition` then pass the numpy array:

```
example.loc[0, 'condition'] = condition.reindex(example.loc[0].index).values
```

**Note** you don't assign with chain index, i.e. `.loc[].loc[]`, but do a `.loc[ind, column]`.

Output:

```
                col_1     col_2  condition
ind_1 ind_2                               
0     0      0.295983  0.241758      False
      1      0.707799  0.765772       True
      2      0.822369  0.062530       True
      3      0.816543  0.621883      False
      4      0.048521  0.738549       True
1     0      0.433304  0.527344      False
      1      0.727886  0.557176      False
      2      0.653163  0.686719      False
      3      0.020094  0.887114      False
      4      0.777072  0.506128      False
```

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Also in this example a simple `example.loc[0, 'condition'] = condition.values` would also do. Thanks :)